# Cross validation and standard error

Tags: orange

I'm performing a CV and I need to report the score with its error, but it only returns the score's average from the folds. Is there a way to either show each folder's score or find the standard error from the folds?

import Orange
data = in_data
knn = Orange.classification.KNNLearner(n_neighbors=5)
res = Orange.evaluation.testing.CrossValidation(data,[knn])
print(Orange.evaluation.scoring.CA(res),Orange.evaluation.scoring.AUC(res))